# placing functions executed by multiple threads into a Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

i am currently creating a Library Simulator within Java. This library has multiple borrowers which are threads. 
Each Borrower thread performs a list of functions e.g.(create borrow list,borrow books from library, return books to library). An Array of borrowers is created within a model class,and each thread is started within a for loop. I am currently having an issue with regards to having the functions run by the borrowers put in a type of output queue, whereby the first function entered by the first Borrower is run etc.

My question is, is there a way to, instead of executing each function when the each borrower thread gets to it, put the functions from all threads into an output queue which it will work through?

Comment: You might have a look at Java's BlockingQueue implementations (such as ArrayBlockingQueue) which provides a convenient collection implementation for a Producer-Consumer pattern like the one you are talking about.

Comment: Objects that you put to a queue can be any: data objects, Strategies, lambda functions... what is the issue?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is,instead of each thread executing one by one, i would rather that they perform a certain function one by one. An example would be "asking the library for a set of books requested".

Comment: Are you asking how to get rid of the "borrower" threads altogether?  That's what I would do if I was asked to implement a high-performance, scalable, lean-and-mean library simulator; but the downside is, my code would be harder to understand than what you describe.  Using threads, which do one thing at a time independently of one another, is a very intuitive way to model _people_, who also do only one thing at a time, and often, independently of one another.

Comment: My high-performance library simulator would look like an operating system scheduler, with stateful "borrower" objects (kind of like operating system processes), and different queues (including a time-ordered sleep queue) for each of the things that a borrower might have to wait for.  When it became time for one of my borrowers to do something (i.e., advance its state), my scheduler would pick it off whatever queue, and add it to the queue of a thread pool (kind of like an OS "run queue"), and a pool thread would call an appropriate method to update the borrower and put it on its next queue.)

Comment: no i need the threads, what im trying to do is this. Each borrower thread executes certain tasks with random intervals. What i am trying to do is place them in a queue which outputs each task, once completed, onto the terminal, rather than the tasks and their outputs being spewed out randomly once the timer has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem using `BlockingDeque`([Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html), first in, first out).
The consumer thread pops the first `Task` from the deque and processes it. Once finished he reports and takes the next Task and so on.
Other Threads - in your case borrowers - just put any Task into the deque in the last position.

Hope this helps!